# D3 layout tree is not rendering

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i don't know why D3 layout tree is not rendering.i wanted to render D3 layout in time being in page body.i have tried to render both "body" or Div but it was not rendered. 
please suggest?what should be need to done in my side.

below is edited code

```
    var treeData = {
            name: "/",
            contents: [
        {
            name: "Applications",
            contents: [
                { name: "Mail.app" },
                { name: "iPhoto.app" },
                { name: "Keynote.app" },
                { name: "iTunes.app" },
                { name: "XCode.app" },
                { name: "Numbers.app" },
                { name: "Pages.app" }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "System",
            contents: []
        },
        {
            name: "Library",
            contents: [
                {
                    name: "Application Support",
                    contents: [
                        { name: "Adobe" },
                        { name: "Apple" },
                        { name: "Google" },
                        { name: "Microsoft" }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "Languages",
                    contents: [
                        { name: "Ruby" },
                        { name: "Python" },
                        { name: "Javascript" },
                        { name: "C#" }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "Developer",
                    contents: [
                        { name: "4.2" },
                        { name: "4.3" },
                        { name: "5.0" },
                        { name: "Documentation" }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "opt",
            contents: []
        },
        {
            name: "Users",
            contents: [
                { name: "pavanpodila" },
                { name: "admin" },
                { name: "test-user" }
            ]
        }
    ]
    };
    var height = 300;
    var width = 300;
    var diameter = 960;
    var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .sort(null)
    .size([height, width - 120])
    .children(function (d) {

        return (!d.contents || d.contents.length === 0) ? null : d.contents;
    });

    var nodes = tree.nodes(treeData);
    var links = tree.links(nodes);

    var svg = d3.select("#pie_chart_1").append("svg")
    .attr("width", diameter)
    .attr("height", diameter - 150)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + ",50)");

    var link = d3.svg.diagonal()
     .projection(function (d) {
         return [d.y, d.x];
     });

     layoutRoot.selectAll(".link")
     .data(links)
     .enter()
     .append("path")
     .attr("class", "link")
     .attr("d", link);






    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
  .data(links)
.enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("d", link);

    var nodeGroup = layoutRoot.selectAll(".node")
     .data(nodes)
     .enter()
     .append("g")
     .attr("class", "node")
     .attr("transform", function (d) {
         return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
     });

     nodeGroup.append("circle")
     .attr("class", "node-dot")
     .attr("r", options.nodeRadius);

     nodeGroup.append("text")
     .attr("text-anchor", function (d) {
         return d.children ? "end" : "start";
     })
     .attr("dx", function (d) {
         var gap = 2 * options.nodeRadius;
         return d.children ? -gap : gap;
     })
     .attr("dy", 3)
     .text(function (d) {
         return d.name;
     });

    }
```

Comment: You seem to insert the SVG-elements into an HTML5 document. You dont need the namespacing `svg:` there.

Comment: i have removed but still it's not working?pls suggest

Comment: When I try to test your code, a lot of variables are undefined.

Comment: sorry i have update the code but still not rendering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your current (given) code:

- The last `}` has to be removed.
- `layoutRoot` is undefined and probably should be `svg`
- `options` is undefined (but that's probably just a missing part in the code).

Here is a [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/K77GK/).

*Actually, you should be able to resolve all those problems just by using the console and working your way through the problems shown.*